# mergesort algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

First let me say that this is hw so I am looking for more advice than an answer.  I am to write a program to read an input sequence and then produce an array of links giving the values in ascending order.

The first line of the input file is the length of the sequence (n) and each of the remaining n lines is a non-negative integer. The
first line of the output indicates the subscript of the smallest input value. Each of the remaining output lines is a triple
consisting of a subscript along with the corresponding input sequence and link values.

(The link values are not initialized before the recursive sort begins. Each link will be initialized to -1 when its sequence value is placed in a single element list at bottom of recursion tree)

The output looks something like this:

```
0  3  5
1  5  2
2  6  3
3  7  -1
4  0  6
5  4  1
6  1  7
7  2  0
```

Where (I think) the last column is the subscripts, the center is the unsorted array, and the last column is the link values.  I have the code already for the mergeSort and understand how it works I am only just confused and how the links get put into place.

Comment: What do you mean by *links*?

Comment: Not 100% but its looking like I'll have a separate array of "link" elements all starting at -1 and somewhere during the mergesort they get assigned an int from the original array.  The whole idea is very confusing to me.

Comment: This is a very aconventional way of sorting data.  Even if we pretend that the elements of the main array are too big to move around and the _links_ allow us to connect things together, it is not clear how the link values work.

Comment: Updated the question to hopefully be a little more clear.

Comment: It would go a **long** way to show an example of the **input** that produced the output you decided to show us. We can get from point-a-to-b much faster when one point is not held in secrecy.

Comment: the first column are the subscripts the middle column is the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used vector of structures to hold the three values of each line.

The major steps are:

- initialize the indexes and read the values from the input
- sort the vector by value
- determine the links
- sort (back) the vector by index

Here is a sketch of the code:

```
struct Element {
    int index;
    int value;
    int nextIndex; // link
}

Element V[N + 1];
int StartIndex;

V[i].index = i;
V[i].value = read_from_input;

sort(V); // by value

startIndex = V[0].index;
V[i].nextIndex = V[i + 1].index;
V[N].nextIndex = -1;

sort(V); // by index
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I get the majority of it but what is N suppose to represent?

Comment: N is the number of elements in the sequence minus one. In your example it's 7.